# Ember.Select error in IE8

Tags: ember.js

I have a sign up form with a country drop down selector which is working fine in Webkit / Firefox / IE9 but when loading the view in IE8 (and IE7 I think, don't recall 100% and I don't really care about IE7 support anyway), it throws an error:

`'this.$().0.selectedIndex' is null or not an object`

I've tried to reduce this to a simple example, which is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/HHw3y/ but unfortunately I can't even get it to run in IE8, it complains about `'console' is undefined` in the ember-latest.js, which is not super useful.

It's definitely the select though, as I can take it out and the rest of the form view inserts fine. Is this an Ember bug? If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in a prior ember release which caused the `'console' is undefined` error that you mention above. It's been fixed in the latest version.